# update eclipse workspace with ant-errors

Tags: eclipse, ant, pdflatex

I have LaTeX project that is hosted in the eclipse environment. To compile the LaTeX code I'm using an ant script that calls `pdflatex.exe` from a local MiKTeX installation. This works fine for me so far.

Now the question: In case the compilation with `pdflatex.exe` detects some errors in the `.tex` files. Is there any way to tell eclipse from the ant script, what files have errors and to mark those files in the project explorer with a red mark or something so that they are easily to identify?

The marks are called *label decorations*. How do I set them via an ant script? Is there some file-property that could be set eventually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add error markers on project resources from an Ant script, but you could try [TeXlipse](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/screenshots/) plugin that may do the work for you.